# Are there any bibliography styles that look like this?

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style, chicago-style

I realize this might seem very basic, but I have been looking all day and I cannot find a bibliography style that will give me references like the following:

> Baker, M. & K. Hale. 1990. Relativized Minimality and pronoun incorporation.
>   Linguistic Inquiry 21:289–297.

I gather that this is supposed to be at least one version of Chicago style, but chicago.bst appears to turn out refs that look almost exactly like APA style, which is totally wrong.

I figure there must be a style like this already out there. Anyone know?

Comment: For specific examples, it isn't too hard to modify the `chicago.bst` (after copying and renaming, of course) to get what you want. E.g., changing the year formatting and the journal formatting. But the format you give doesn't agree with http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/tools_citationguide.html either.

Comment: Really this is not sufficient to show what the style is, since it simply gives the style for a journal article, and not for any other type of reference.  So it would be helpful to point to the actual style requirements you need in the question. (See my answer below if you're looking for the Linguistic Society of America unified style.)

Answer (score 7):

Consider making your own by running:

`latex makebst`

from the commandline. This will provide a series of multiple choice questions (--there are quite a few, but it's doable--) about how you want things you look, and getting something like this should not be too hard.

Comment: I wonder if there's a similar tool for biblatex...

Comment: @Seamus: No there isn't a similar tool for `biblatex` because  `biblatex` is desidned so that there are latex methods for changing everything.  The reason `makebst` exists is because hacking `.bst` files is not for the faint of heart (or stack language impaired.)

Comment: @Alan Munn Having tried to read and understand `.cbx` and `.bbx` files, I find that a makebst tool might still be worthwhile for biblatex...

Comment: @Seamus point taken; but most people will not have to create a whole one from scratch. I think what's missing mainly, though, is a good tutorial on making minor tweaks to existing `.bbx` and `.cbx` files.

Answer (score 2):

If this is the same as the LSA Unified Style, (guessing from your choice of example reference) you can get a .bst version of it here:

[unified.bst](http://celxj.org/downloads/unified.bst)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
\usepackage[style=biblatex-chicago]{biblatex}
```

There are also a lot of cite styles